Angular Material UI - How to add onBlur validation for checkboxes/radio buttons?
I'm trying to create some simple checkboxes and radio buttons with Angular Material UI. The problem I'm having is getting the red outline onBlur effect when the field is required and the user doesn't select an option. I added the requiredTrue validator, but it doesn't work. Sample HTML below.
    <div>
        @for (i of checkboxValues; track i){
            <mat-checkbox 
                [value]="i.key"
                [checked]="i.selected"             
            >
                {{i.value}}
            </mat-checkbox>
        }
    </div>

<mat-radio-group [formControl]="radioFormControl">
    @for (i of radioValues; track i){        
        <mat-radio-button 
            [value]="opt" 
        >
            {{i.value}}
        </mat-radio-button>
    }
</mat-radio-group>

I tried wrapping the <mat-option> and <mat-checkboxes> in a <mat-form-field> but I end up getting an error related to 'Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl' which I can't seem to resolve. I'm new to angular so maybe there's something I'm missing.

The answer to your question is to use custom CSS to create the red border, the CSS will look like below.
.mat-mdc-radio-group.ng-touched.ng-invalid {
  .mdc-radio__outer-circle {
    border-color: red !important;
  }
  .mdc-label {
    color: red;
  }
}

.mat-mdc-checkbox.ng-touched.ng-invalid {
  .mdc-checkbox__background {
    border-color: red !important;
  }
  .mdc-label {
    color: red !important;
  }
}

The main problem in your approach is with the checkboxes, red validation cannot be placed, unless you want the user to mandatory check the check-box. Other than that, it's possible to be done for radio group easily, without the mat form field.
Full Code:
HTML:
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="form.markAllAsTouched();">
  <mat-label>Enter your Selection</mat-label>
  <br />
  <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" formControlName="radios">
    @for (item of radioValues; track item){
    <mat-radio-button [value]="item.id">{{item.label}}</mat-radio-button>
    }
  </mat-radio-group>
  <br />
  @if(form.get('radios'); as radio) { @if (radio?.touched &&
  radio?.errors?.required) {
  <mat-error>Selection is required</mat-error>
  } }
  <hr />
  <mat-label>Enter your Checkboxes</mat-label>
  @for (item of checkboxValues; track item){
  <mat-checkbox [value]="item.key" [formControlName]="item.value">
    {{item.value}}
  </mat-checkbox>
  }
  <hr />
  <br />
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>

TS:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

/**
 * @title Basic radios
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'radio-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'radio-overview-example.html',
  styleUrl: 'radio-overview-example.css',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatRadioModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    CommonModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
  ],
})
export class RadioOverviewExample {
  radioValues = [
    { id: 1, label: 'apple' },
    { id: 2, label: 'banana' },
  ];
  checkboxValues = [
    { key: 'apple', value: 'apple', selected: false },
    { key: 'banana', value: 'banana', selected: false },
    { key: 'orange', value: 'orange', selected: false },
  ];
  form = new FormGroup({
    radios: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
  });

  ngOnInit() {
    this.checkboxValues.forEach((item: any) => {
      this.form.addControl(
        item.value,
        new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
      );
    });
    // this.form.get('radios')!.markAsTouched();
    // this.form.get('radios')!.markAsDirty();
  }
}

Click on submit to see the errors.
Stackblitz Demo

Does material-ui not provide this built-in for checkboxes/radio? I find that odd since they provide this feature for text, select, etc...

@bestfirstsearch Its usually not standard for the validation message on checkboxes and radio buttons, because usually one of the radio buttons will be checked. As for checkboxes, as I explained, a checkbox can be false, but that does not mean its not valid, so we have to create a custom validation to suit our requirement
